# What does it mean if $\beta$ is insignificant in the CAPM model?

Tags: risk-models

What can we say about an asset which $\beta$ calculated using the CAPM model (regressing the excess returns of the stock vs excess returns of the market) is insignificant?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the process of *estimating* your $\beta$ (since if you ask about significance, you have an estimation viewpoint): you try to fit a linear model between your returns $r$ and a factor returns $F$ like

$$r = \beta \cdot F + \epsilon,$$

where $\epsilon$ is your *tracking error* around the factor (or more accurately around the part of your returns explained by the factor).

Your question about $\beta$ being significantly different from zero, can now be read as a linear regression significance question. They is a common knowledge about this.

- For instance the [t-test](http://reliawiki.org/index.php/Simple_Linear_Regression_Analysis#Hypothesis_Tests_in_Simple_Linear_Regressionhttp://reliawiki.org/index.php/Simple_Linear_Regression_Analysis#Hypothesis_Tests_in_Simple_Linear_Regression)
- but you can ask [a lot of other questions](http://www.uv.es/uriel/4%20Hypothesis%20testing%20in%20the%20multiple%20regression%20model.pdf) about the significance of your $\beta$.
- "of course" you can face different conclusions coming from different tests, here is a [cross-stackexchange link about this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24720/significance-of-coefficients-in-linear-regression-significant-t-test-vs-non-sig).